# Exit while loop once input has ended

Tags: c++, file, while-loop

I am writing a program and in one part of the program I need to read in integer inputs from user and multiply each number by the mod of two other numbers and then convert that number to its ASCII character value and output it to a file.  But all of that works fine... I just cannot get the loop to end.  Every time I enter some integers, for example 67 78 100, it will convert each number and output it to the file like its suppose to but instead of continuing with the rest of the program once its done it goes back to the top of the loop and asks the user for another input.  So how can I get the loop to end after it has converted all the numbers and stored them in a file.

Relevant code...

```
while(cin >> f && f != '\n')
{
    num = f * b % N;
    CharFile << char(num) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should define what it means to "convert all numbers".

Comment: I convert every number inputted to a character using inverse mod and ASCII.  But that is not the part I am having trouble with.  I just need to figure out how to end the loop once all the inputted numbers have been converted.  For example if I enter 100 56 87 I want the loop to end once 87 is converted.

Comment: are you entering all numbers at once (100 56 87 `enter`)? or you want to read them one by one (100, `enter key`, 56, `enter`, 87, `enter`,...

Comment: I am entering all numbers as once.  For example 100 87 65 enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cin is meant for formatted text, meaning it will not give you things like newline characters.  To get unformatted character, try cin.get() to see if you're reading newline:

```
while(cin >> f)
{
    num = f * b % N;
    CharFile << char(num) << endl;
    if (cin.get() == '\n') break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly!  Now I am basically done with my program.

Answer (score 0):

use `break;`. For more information, check this website out: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_break_statement.htm

Comment: I am pretty sure that's all you need. Well you should know where and how to use it. Anyways, it seems like you already got your answer